# Unable to connect to a port in an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have an EC2 instance that is running a Flask application, this is how my code looks:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET"])
def HOME():
    return {"mensaje": "Proyecto OLC2!"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug = True, port=4000)
```

Since I'm running the app on port 4000,this is how I set the inbound and outbound rules:

[image]

[image]

It seems that the app is running succesfully

[image]

But when I try to connect using the public IP and the port 4000 (publicIp:4000/), it gets me the error "Unable to connect" How can I solve this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the public IP address for EC2 instance? Did you check the Network ACL on the subnet, to make sure it's not blocking that port (by default it doesn't, but just in case). Did you turn on the firewall on EC2 instance itself maybe? In that case you would have to allow that connection. Also, do you get a proper response if you curl from the server itself?

Comment: Security groups are stateful. You don't need any of those outbound rules.

Comment: Run the app on 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1 (see [here](https://www.nylas.com/blog/why-wont-my-flask-application-run-dev/)). Why? See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0).

Comment: @jarmod I just deleted the outbound rules but I can't still connect to the port

Comment: @jarmod Oh thank you!!! changing to 0.0.0.0 solved the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have is that your Flask app is, by default, listening on 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback interface. That's only reachable from within the host itself.

For external clients to be able to reach your app, it needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 which will allow the app to accept traffic from all of the available network interfaces. Or you can bind it to one specific network interface, if you prefer, by supplying the IP address associated with that interface.